# Convert javascript <script> to javascript .js file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mailchimp

Please consider me an absolute noob at Javascript. 
I only have a bit of experience with HTML, CSS and a little bit of PHP (wordpress relevant).

I have the following pop-up sign up form from Mailchimp that uses script tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us9.list-manage.com","uuid":"3fb38776176e5e9150749d44d","lid":"17c36a2172"}) })</script>
```

I am supposed to put it into the header, but since I am using a purchased child theme on Wordpress I cannot do this without issues with updates.  The way around this is to use a plugin... I need to put this code into a .js file instead of the header. I have absolutely no idea how to do this and get it to run.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Open link https://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js and copy the code into js file

Comment: Don't forget to include file: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, open the link, copy the contents to your clipboard, paste it to YOURFILE.js on your local computer.

I'm replying to reinforce that and to add: Do not include the opening and closing SCRIPT tags and that etc. from the line above, that stuff will cause errors.

Once you've properly named and saved YOURFILE.js to a location where your plugin can access it,, you should be home free.

The other option for adding custom JS to Wordpress, add YOURFILE.js to your theme and register with a command in your functions.php file it per the instructions provided by Wordpress.

See instructions at https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#scripts